# Audio plugin advice for Logic Pro 8

Tags: logic

I'm trying to find the free demo downloads for the following plugins:

IKmultimedia amplitude metal
IKmultimedia amplitude SVT
Waves SSL bundle
Steven Slate everything bundle

I'm running Logic 8 on OS 10.5.8 with a G5 Power PC.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt most of those have ever been made for PPC

Comment: Hmm... didn't realise SSL was so old - http://www.waves.com/downloads/v6 but PPC support says 10.4.11 - 10.5.6